# Extracting only numbers within a list

Tags: scheme, racket

Is there a way to extract only numbers within a list?
I'm using the beginner language package so I cannot use filter which is a bummer.

(list a 1 2 b d 3 5) => 1 2 3 5 etc
I want to use this as a part of my helper function but I cannot figure it out!

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally this problem should be solved using the [`filter`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29) higher-order procedure, like this:

```
(filter number? '(a 1 2 b d 3 5))
=> '(1 2 3 5)
```

... But because this looks like a homework, I'll give you some hints on how to solve the problem by hand, just fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (only-numbers lst)
  (cond (<???>                        ; is the list empty?
         <???>)                       ; return the em´pty list
        (<???>                        ; is the 1st element in the list a number?
         (cons <???>                  ; then cons the first element
               (only-numbers <???>))) ; and advance the recursion
        (else                         ; otherwise
         (only-numbers <???>))))      ; simply advance the recursion
```

Notice that this solution follows a well-known template, a *recipe* of sorts for recursively processing a list and in turn creating a new list as output. Don't forget to test your procedure:

```
(only-numbers '(a 1 2 b d 3 5))
=> '(1 2 3 5)

(only-numbers '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(1 2 3 5)

(only-numbers '(a b c d e))
=> '()
```